# odom frame keeps moving in ROS GPS robot_localization

Tags: ros, localization, sensor-fusion, gps, ros-noetic

I am using two instances of ROS *robot_localization* package to get the local and global odometry. In the local one, I am fusing *IMU* and *twist* messages. It is working fine. But when I use the second instance where *map* and *odom* frame both should be fixed points, one of them is moving. I set *map* as the fixed frame, then *odom* is moving. Why is that? Odom should remain fixed at the initial starting point. *base_link* with respect to *odom* is working fine but since *odom* is moving, *base_link* with respect to *map* is not working.

In the image, you can see the *map* frame is the big axes. *odom* frame was there too. But as I move the robot, the *odom* frame starts moving. The red lines are local odometry and green ones are global odometry.

[image]
1st instance:

```
ekf_se_odom: # Used only for broadcasting odom to base_link transforms
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: true
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_link
  world_frame: odom
```

2nd instance:

```
ekf_se_map:
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: true
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_link
  world_frame: map

  publish_tf: true
```

navsat_node:

```
navsat_transform:
  frequency: 30
  delay: 3.0
  magnetic_declination_radians: 0.0842
  yaw_offset: -1.57080
  zero_altitude: true
  broadcast_utm_transform: true
  publish_filtered_gps: true
  use_odometry_yaw: false
  wait_for_datum: false
  broadcast_utm_transform_as_parent_frame: false
```

I am using gazebo husky simulation.

Comment: Are you sure, you do not have other nodes running in the background? Using Ctrl + C does stop the stop but sometimes, it runs in the background.

Answer (score 1):

> Odom should remain fixed at the initial starting point.

This assumption is not correct, as map->odom is allowed to change. You have configured your 2nd instance to publish this update.

An update to the map->odom TF is typically done to correct for drift in odom->base_link since it comes from an odometry source.

The purpose of this to make the overall transform map->base_link a globally accurate source for localisation and mapping purpose which may have discontinuous jumps (e.g. Due to loop closure from SLAM), while maintaining odom->base_link as an approximately accurate but more importantly continuously varying TF for control and state estimation purposes.

The purpose of this structure is formalised and documented in [REP-105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html)